# Задать вложенному элементу с фиксированной позицией ширину 100% внутри родительского блока

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть вложенный элемент с выпадающим списком `.company-title-wrap`, которому необходимо задать `position: fixed;` и при этом он должен занимать 100% ширины родительского блока. При этом родительский блок не занимает 100% ширины окна браузера (сетка bootstrap `col-md-8`).

Если задать задать вложенному блоку `width:100%;`, то он растягивается на всю ширину окна браузера. Если не задавать ширину 100%, то он сжимается.

```
.company-title-wrap {
background: #fff;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
text-align: center;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}
```

Какие есть способы зафиксировать блок и задать ему ширину 100% родительского блока?

[Полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/t8pnrv7x/1/)

Comment: Насколько я знаю, придется использовать javascript. Абсолютное позиционирование не учитывает некоторые свойства родительских элементов.

Comment: фиксированный блок работает только с основным окном и его размерами. Если устанавливать ширину и высоту в 100%, они будут взяты от окна. Если требуется сделать фиксированное окно, нужно взять с помощью `javascript` размеры нужного окна и присвоить их. Но непонятно зачем вам это нужно, и зачем вы используете фиксированные блоки так

Comment: ясно. значит для решения этой задачи без js не обойтись... спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделала c помощью jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
$('.company-title-wrap').css('width', $('.row.changed').width());
});
```

[Полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/t8pnrv7x/2/)

**UPD**

Этот способ работает только если изменять ширину окна. При открытии страницы на моб.устр. скрипт не срабатывает (т.к. там ширина не меняется). Как заставить скрипт срабатывать мгновенно, не дожидаясь изменения ширины окна?

Что-то типа этого:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.company-title-wrap').css('width', $('.row.changed').width());
});
});
```

Что необходимо изменить чтобы заработало?

Comment: `function resize() {
    $('.company-title-wrap').css('width', $('.row.changed').width());
}

$(document).ready(resize);
$(window).resize(resize);`

Comment: Хотя у себя я делал так $(document).on('ready', function () {
    resize();
    $(window).on('resize', resize);
}); Это позволяет повесить обработчик на resize после загрузки страницы, а не раньше.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добиться схожего результата по другому: зафиксировать не элемент внутри блока, а контейнер с этим элементом внутри страницы.

1. Создать отдельный контейнер, зафиксировать его и растянуть по ширине с помощью `left:0; right:0;`.
2. Внутри контейнера расположить ряд с бутстраповской колонкой, идентичной нашему "родительскому" блоку.
3. В эту колонку поместить выпадающий список с кнопками.

Проверьте результат, пожалуйста: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/n4dz6g8q/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.fix-it {
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
.fix-it > div {
  background: #fff;
}
.add-padding {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.company-title-wrap {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.company-title-wrap a {
  border-bottom: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 2.5;
}

.company-title-wrap .icon-caret {
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: -29px -1247px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 8px;
  height: 5px;
}

.company-title-wrap .bttn {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container fix-it">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="company-title-wrap dropdown">
        <div class="company-title-button-wrap">
          <button type="button" class="bttn active"><span class="icons icon-bttn-mapping"></span></button>
          <button type="button" class="bttn"><span class="icons icon-bttn-option"></span></button>
        </div>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          dropdown <span class="icons icon-caret"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row add-padding">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="group-list">

        <div class="group-list-item clearfix">
          <a href="">
            <span class="pull-left">
                <b>list</b>
                <div>list</div>
            </span>
            <span class="pull-right">в отпуске</span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="group-list-item">
          <a href="">
            <b>list</b>
            <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
            <div>list</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="group-list-item">
          <a href="">
            <b>list</b>
            <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
            <div>list</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="group-list-item">
          <a href="">
            <b>list</b>
            <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
            <div>list</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="group-list-item">
          <a href="">
            <b>list</b>
            <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
            <div>list</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="group-list-item">
          <a href="">
            <b>list</b>
            <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
            <div>list</div>
          </a>
        </div>
 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за решение. но не помогло. блок растягивается на всю ширину окна браузера

Comment: @MarinaVoronova Можно увидеть код, в котором пробуете это решение?

Comment: ваш код тоже рабочий (но у меня не получилось применить). решила использовать jquery

Comment: @MarinaVoronova К сожалению, только сейчас заметил ваш комментарий. Если покажете свой код, то попробую помочь. Чем он отличается от [вашего фидла](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/t8pnrv7x/1/)? И посмотрите вариант этого же решения [на англоязычном сайте](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925768/). Он может оказаться удобнее.